# Disable a button inside a label element using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a way to disable a 'inner-button' that is inside a label tag.

I have a button that is created in a label:

```
<label for="UploadFile" class="inner-button" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Upload File" onclick="SetFileName()" id="upload">
                                            <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                                                <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x img-responsive"></i>
                                                <i class="fa fa-upload fa-stack-1x fa-inverse img-responsive"></i>
                                            </span>
                                        </label>
```

I want to disable that element using a radio buttons in a similar format like that:

```
 <label>
 <input type="radio" id="chkDisableOnClick"name="radiobButton" onclick="document.getElementById('upload').disabled = true;"/> 
 </label>
```

I did not have any luck at the moment. Once the radio button is clicked, the button inside the Label is not disabled.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post you CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use for example pointer-events css property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events).

```
label[disabled]{
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`label` doesn't have a disable property, you'll need to add a class to disable the object. For example:

```
.disabled {
   color: darkgrey;
   background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Ahh, that's unfortunate that label don't have disable property :(. Anyway, thanks for the answer, works fine now.

Comment: just adding a css class won't stop the user for clicking on the label and call the `onclick` function, you'll need to unbind the onclick also... or change the label to another element that makes more sense than a label that is designed to be used as a readOnly element

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that. But it gave me idea how to disable it.